# Opening text files from finder: Unable to find application

Tags: macos, finder, text-editor

Since I updated my OSX to version 10.9.1 I am unable to open text files from the Finder.

I always opened the files with the default TextEditor. I've tried to change the default application from TextEditor to Sublime Text 2, which results in exactly the same error:

"Unable to find the application"

When I open TextEditor or Sublime Text 2 I can successfully open the file and view it's contents.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: You could try resetting the Launch Services database by running `$(locate lsregister) -kill -domain local -domain system -domain user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the default app to open .txt files using Get Info

1. Left click a text file
2. Choose "Get Info"
3. Under "Open with:" choose the app you want to use as the default
4. Click "Change All..."
5. Click "Continue"

Comment: I tried this without success the first time. After a reboot I tried the suggested solution again, now it works. Weird stuff :)